# Dynamically display bootstrap table using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I'll be getting the column names and and the data from hybris server and it need not necessarily be the same number every time. I'm using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) to make the table. Till now I've been defining the columns on the front end using the columns field. Like this:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  columns:[{
    field: '',
    checkbox: true
  }, {
    field:'status',
    title: 'Book Name',
  }],
  data: bookDataList
});
```

This is what I've been using till now. But now this data with maybe additional columns i'll be getting from a server. How do I set up the table dynamically during run time?

Comment: Where is the relevant source code to your question and what changes are you trying to make?

Comment: I've added it in.

Comment: The code does not explain the problem. Where is the input, where is the error message?

Comment: The input will be json data. There is no error message because I don't know how to implement this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your column definition (and column data ) pulled from your server.

If you already have a URL for your data - use the url option for the bootstrap table and just pull the dynamic column data.

[Pull column definition and column data from server for dynamic bootstrapTable](http://jsfiddle.net/jimkennelly/tz4cjq6x/)

```js
$(function() {

//note: myjson.com - handy way to test json 
var link = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/oqnet';


$.ajax({
  url: link,
  cache: false
})
  .done(function( d ) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: d.columnDefinition,
    data: d.data
  });
});
  
  

});
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I also figured out another way of doing it. I'd be getting the order of the columns from Hybris and I'll have a global mapped column list on the front end. I can use a  array and push the required column data as and when it comes.

Comment: @Nightshade could you show us your solution in your post?